# Bulk move User Stories under a Feature

Tags: azure-devops

I have migrated lots of historical closed User Stories under an Epic from my previous system.
I want to move them under a newly created Feature that is under the Epic.
I can bulk change parent from the backlog but these user stories don't appear in the backlog.  I don't seem to be able to do it with a query.
So how can i move them?

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> Bulk move User Stories under a Feature

You could query it with `Only return items that have matching links` to get all the User Stories under the Epic, like:

[image]

Then we could [Import/Export of Workitems from Excel in Azure DevOps](https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/import-export-of-workitems-from-excel-in-azure-devops/), and update the workitems.